# Serialization of scalar JSON in Flutter's Ferry Graphql

Tags: json, flutter, graphql, jsonserializer

I have the following JSON scalar:

```
"""
The `JSON` scalar type represents JSON values as specified by [ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf).
"""
scalar JSON
```

which I am trying to convert since my `query` is accepting `input: JSON`. When testing using graphql playground, query is JSON object thus the following works:

```
query {
  carts(where: {
    owner:{id: "xxx"}
    store:{name: "yyy"}
  }) {
    id
  }
}
# query is the starting from the where: {...}
```

However when using ferry, I have trouble converting the `scalar JSON`, I've tried to convert it to `String` and/or `Map<String, dynamic>` but both are throwing errors. I am trying to write my custom serializer following this link:
https://ferrygraphql.com/docs/custom-scalars/
however it is throwing the same error like when I'm trying converting it to `Map<String, dynamic>`, I have no idea what to convert to as dart do not have any type of JsonObject and usually `Map` is suffice for json representation. Any idea guys? I'd appreciate any clues as I've exhausted all of my options and am currently bruteforce trying